# Iterate through Javascript regex matches to modify original string

Tags: javascript, regex

Just wondering the best way to replace in place matches on a string.

```
value.replace("bob", "fred");
```

for example, works, but I want each instance of "bob" to be replaced with a random string I have stored in an array. Just doing a regex match returns me the matching text, but doesn't allow me to replace it in the original string. Is there a simple way to do this?

For example I would expect the string:

```
"Bob went to the market. Bob went to the fair. Bob went home"
```

To maybe pop out as

```
"Fred went to the market. John went to the fair. Alex went home"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can replace with the value of a function call:

```
var names = ["Fred", "John", "Alex"];
var s = "Bob went to the market. Bob went to the fair. Bob went home";
s = s.replace(/Bob/g, function(m) {
    return names[Math.floor(Math.random() * names.length)];
});
```

This gives for example:

```
"John went to the market. Fred went to the fair. John went home"
```

Comment: Whoa. That is perfect. Thanks!